# Chosen.js: animating the dropdown with slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So, the [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin is great. Does anyone know how can I add a little effect to the dropdown select box to make it slideDown/slideUp when clicked rather than pop-opening with no animation?

Answer (score 2):

there's a solution for your problem.

css:

rule `.chosen-container`

add

```
display: none;
```

and remove

```
left: -9999px;
```

Now we must bind some events:

```
$('.chosen-select').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
    $(this).next('.chosen-container').children('.chosen-drop').slideDown(400);
}).on('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function () {
    $(this).next('.chosen-container').children('.chosen-drop').slideUp(400);
});
```

That's all!

Comment: Great workaround, but you'll need to edit chosen.css like this:

Find:
`.chosen-container .chosen-drop {...`
Remove:
`left: -9999px;`
Add:
`display: none;`

Find:
`.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {...`
Remove:
`left: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Chosen doesn't have much of an API, so I'm working with [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), a more advanced successor to Chosen. The syntax switch from Chosen to Select2 is fairly trivial.

This gets you close, but Select2 hides the search results on close. You'd have to deal with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9WgAB/

```
$("#mySelect").select2().on('open',function(){
    $('.select2-drop').hide().slideDown();
}).on('close',function(){
    $('.select2-drop').show().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know about Select2. Will try your suggestion and report back here asap.

Comment: Great plugin, but the JSFiddle example doesn't animate. Current Safari and Chrome.

Comment: that script doesn't work with newer versions of select2